# Issue in Sum -Identities Not hold?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, products

I have a sum:

$$\sum _{k=1}^n i \log \left(e^{i k}\right)$$
then using [identities:](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Product.html) I have:

$$i \log \left(\prod _{k=1}^n e^{i k}\right)=i \log \left(e^{\frac{1}{2} i n (1+n)}\right)$$

,but this identities not hold for my function. I put numericall value $n=1..10$ to Product:

```
{-1., -3., 0.283185, 2.56637, -2.43363, -2.15044, -2.86726, 1.69911, -1.0177, 1.54867}
```

In sum I have:

```
{-1., -3., -6., -3.71681, -2.43363, -2.15044, -2.86726, -4.58407,-7.30089, -4.73452}
```

values are different in the third, fourth, eighth, ninth, and tenth.

$$\sum _{k=1}^n \log (f(k))\neq \log \left(\prod _{k=1}^n f(k)\right)$$

Why this identities not hold for my function?

Comment: What branch of the logarithm are you using?  It basically comes down to things like: $$-1=e^{\pi i}=e^{-\pi i}\implies\ln(-1)=~?$$

Comment: In Mathematica: $\ln (-1)=i \pi$

Comment: I'ts not, in general, true. It's branch-cut dependent. Even so, it'll be true 'in general' with some restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically comes down to what branch of the natural logarithm you are using.  Note that:

$$\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$$

generally holds only when $a,b>0$.  For a quick example of when they don't hold, note that:

$$2\ln(-1)=\ln(-1)+\ln(-1)\ne\ln(1)=0$$

Clearly, $\ln(-1)\ne0$.

Comment: How  find the correct solution to this sum?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk It appears Mathematica does the following: $$\ln(z)=\ln|z|+i\theta,\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$$And thus,$$\ln(e^{ix})=i(x+2\pi k),x+2\pi k\in(-\pi,\pi],k\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: This means that the sum is correctly calculated.and Mathematica calculates in its proper way.?

Comment: Yes.  Indeed, the sum and products are calculated correctly, but they are not equal.

Comment: I'm find the answer to my question,here: http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/